# Mac terminal isn't recognizing wild card

Tags: macos, bash, wildcards

I'm trying to write a script that shrinks all the images in a folder.

From [here](https://robservatory.com/use-sips-to-quickly-easily-and-freely-convert-image-files/) I got this:

```
for i in *.png; do sips -Z 800 "${i}" --out "${i%png}"; done
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: *.png not a valid file - skipping
Error 4: no file was specified
Try 'sips --help' for help using this tool
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is my bash version:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Maybe `noglob` is set. Try `set +f`

Answer (score 2):

The script needs to be executed inside the folder that contains the pictures. If by any means there is no `.png` file inside the current folder the loop assigns `*.png` to the variable `i`. As a result, sips tells you it is not a valid file, which is correct.

Comment: i'm obviously running this on a folder that has .png files in it

Comment: @abbood Directly in it? i.e. not in subdirectories?

Comment: Does `for i in *.png; do echo $i; done` deliver all `.png` files in the folder?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
set +o noglob
```

to stop literal interpretation of wildcards?